# Double integral in derivation of expectation of the product of two random variables

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, independence

Let $Z = XY$ be the product of independent random variables $X, Y$ with distributions $f_X, f_Y$. Then expected value
$$E[Z] = E[XY] = \int\int x f_X(x) y f_Y(y) dx dy = \int x f_X(x) dx \int y f_Y(y) dy = E[X]E[Y]$$
and we could write joint pdf $f_{X,Y}$ as $f_X f_Y$ and split the double integral because of the definition of independence "random variables $X,Y$ are independent if and only if $f_{X|Y}(x|y) = f_X(x)$.

Is it correct? I feel as if I missed some detail.

Comment: Looks good to me!